# Uploading test results to DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm brand new to DevOps.  For user acceptance testing, I want end-users to record [manual] test results on a spread sheet rather than having them entering the results directly in DevOps.  The end-users are not tech savy but they can use Excel.  I know I can do a bulk import of test cases - is there a way to import executed test cases with actual results as well?  Something like:
[Sample .csv import template] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5oaW.png)

Thanks!

I've imported test cases but can't figure out if it's possible to add columns to indicate execution results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry but you cannot directly add "result" filed in the excel file and import it in.
If you would like to update the result into the corresponding test case, you could [associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops).

For example, if your run the test locally by visual studio, after creating the test, go to Test Explorer->choose the needed linked test, right click it and choose Associate to specific Test Case.
Then after the association, you run the test in Visual Studio and the result will  automatically update to the test case.

I hope it could do some help.